# If there is a surjective homomorphism from $R^n$ to $M$, is $M$ finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $M$ is an $R$ module where $R$ is a ring. In Dummit and Foote Chapter 12, they claim that $M$ is finitely generated over $R$ if and only if there exists a surjective $R$-homomorphism from $R^n$ to $M$. The only if part is trivial, but in the book, we do not assume that rings contain $1$, so I can only prove the converse if I further assume that $R^n$ is finitely generated.

If I take $R$ to be the ring of polynomials vanishing at 0, then clearly $R^n$ is not finitely generated, so I fail to see how to prove the claim in the more general case. I have not found any mistakes in the book, which leads me to believe that I am either wrong or missing something subtle.

Comment: Why is $R^n$ not finitely generated?

Comment: I think the notion 'finitely generated over $R$' only really makes sense if $R$ contains $1$. Also, if $R$ is not finitely generated over itself, then clearly the result is false by taking $M=R$.

Comment: It appears to me that generation of modules is first discussed in chapter 10.3, whose first sentence reads "Let R be a ring with 1."

Comment: Definitely seems to be a typo/mistake since my copy of the text (3 ed) says "this is true for any ring $R$".  But it is easy enough to see that is not true.